# Загрузка файла по Uri

Tags: android, download, uri

Добрый день. Я пытаюсь сделать пикер для фото, но столкнулся с такой сложностью. Если выбирать файлы, которые remote, то для них возвращается `Uri`, который начинается с `content://`

ex:

```
Intent { dat=content://com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/d82a9636-9e75-4e70-96c7-bcb1375de12b typ=image/png flg=0x3 }
```

Я не хочу лишать пользователей возможности использовать remote изображения, но не могу найти нигде информации о том, как скачать их на устройство, используя `Uri`. Никто не сталкивался с такой задачей?

Если пользоваться методом

```
public static String generateLocalPathForGallery(Context context, Uri uri) {

    String filePath = null;
    try {
        filePath = getPath(context, uri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    }

    if (filePath != null) {
        return filePath;
    }

    try {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("Probably trying to load pic from remote", e));
        }
    }

    return filePath == null ? uri.getPath() : filePath;
}
```

то результат будет приблизительно следующим

```
/filecache/d82a9636-9e75-4e70-96c7-bcb1375de12b
```

Конечно можно сделать костыль для дропбокса, но это не то решение, которое я пытаюсь найти, так как существует масса приложений, которые позволяют выбирать remote  изображение. Есть ли какой то универсальный способ?

**UPDATE**

Ещё одно микронаблюдение - в интенте приходит ссылка на скачанное изображение, буквально, на конкретном примере: `com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/d82a9636-9e75-4e70-96c7-bcb1375de12b` . But it is the fail. Так как на андроиде, начиная с апи 21 сд карта закрыта для чтения

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь получить путь к удаленному файлу, немного измените вашу концепцию - вам нужен не путь к файлу, а нужен поток к открытому удаленному файлу, пользуясь которым вы сможете скачать файл:

```
inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```